# How To Adjust Gallery Height With CSS

Tags: html, css, image, gallery, image-gallery

I am using `SquareSpace` for the building blocks of my [site](https://ryan-gould-7uht.squarespace.com/portraiture/) and creating some custom CSS to fine tune. I'm trying to get the gallery page to display the images with more height. At the moment they are not very big in the slider, especially when viewed on a large monitor, seems like there is a lot of wasted space.

Using Inspect Element, I found there to be some HTML styling the height and restricting it to `500px`.

```
<div class="slideshow strip main sqs-gallery-design-strip rendered: id="yui_3_17_2_1_1441831607164_254" style="height: 500px; margin-top: 203:5px;">
```

Changing the height from `500px` to `600px` in Firebug works perfectly, so I tried to apply some custom code to in the SquareSpace site. I used:

```
.slideshow strip main sqs-gallery-design-strip rendered {
    height: 600px;
}
```

The injection of code did not have a visible result on the page. Am I writing the CSS incorrectly? Is there something I'm missing here? Please help.. Thank you!

Comment: Try adding !important. The line should be: height: 600px !important;

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache. Sometimes a cache does not refresh on a server.

To clear it on a site, just hit Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rule is close. It should read:

```
.slideshow.strip.main.sqs-gallery-design-strip.rendered {
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, but now I've lost my scaling images. Now, if I decrease the size of the browser window, the images are static at 600px. Is there a way to retain the scaling properties inherent in the template and just increase the maximum size they display on the page?